# Ruby vs. PHP/plugins social networking

Tags: php, ruby, plugins, social-networking

I am in the process of building a site that will contain features comparable to those that social networking sites usually use.  I already built the signup forms, login forms, and forms to add information to the database in PHP/mySQL.  What do people usually use for these types of projects?  Can anyone suggest any good plugins or methods to help me out?  Where is a good place to find these sort of things?  Is it worth it to learn Ruby to do this?  Does Ruby make this much easier?  How can I use jquery in a project such as this?  How should I create the chat rooms / forums / profiles?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should split this up into a number of more specific questions. There are a lot of questions in this one...

Comment: Whoa there, one question at a time.

Comment: It seems a bit silly to me to make a site in one (scripting) language, and force plugins to be written in a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that if your planning on something with more than 10 pages, well it should be more than necesary to start thinking about a framework. As i said many times, i'm a symfony enthusiast and i've been working with it for quite some time for work. Its based on php (you wont need to learn any other language) and implements the MVC object pattern.

It handles from routing, forms, database abstracions and everything else. Also has a plugin project with tons of code. Check the [main project page](http://www.symfony-project.org/) for more details

Comment: Thanks!  What I'm getting at here is how do people usually discover 'plugins' and frameworks such as this one??

Comment: I discoverd it at university in a course about web technoliges. I really recommed you to digg into it, you wont regret it!